# How to detect which user has logged from one server to another(root access only)

Tags: linux, ssh, clearcase

The question seems to be quite confusing plz go through it slowly.

We have 2 servers `loadbuild/clearcase` in which every user has a unique ID and another one is the lab(running on wind-river linux) to which any `loadbuild/clearcase` user can ssh as `**root**@192.xxx.x.x` from the `loadbuild/clearcase` server.

If you observe every `loadbuild/clearcase` user accesses the lab as a same user i.e. **root** I wish to find out which user has logged in to the lab and at what time or has given an ssh `**root**@192.xxx.x.x` from loadbuild/clearcase server to the lab.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following commands on all your servers and see the logging details.

```
 utmpdump /var/log/wtmp
```

If you login as root/or any other user, then that detail will be avialble on your loadbuild/clearcase server.

Answer (score 0):

The `lastlog` command will show you who's logged in, when they logged in, and from where they came from.

Sample output:

```
Username         Port     From             Latest
root             pts/1    192.168.1.150    Wed Dec 18 16:57:55 -0500 2013
```